# Comparison of implemenation of sort functions in Collections utility class

Tags: java, generics

I'm pretty new to Generics usage in Java.

Came across following functions to sort in `Collections.java` class

```
// Sorting based on Comparable
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set((T)a[j]);
    }
}


// Sorting based on Comparator
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator)c);
    ListIterator i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set(a[j]);
    }
}
```

What I want to understand is:

1. Why is `ListIterator` parameterized in sort function based on `Comparable` and why *raw* `ListIterator` is used in sort function based on `Comparator`?
2. In the `for` loop why is type casting (to `T`) needed in sort function based on `Comparable` and why casting is not necessary in `for` loop of sort function based on `Comparator`?

I feel the following code would have more type safe for the comparator based sort function:

```
public static <T> void Sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        Object[] a = list.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator)c);
        ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
        for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
            i.next();
            i.set((T)a[j]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> why raw ListIterator is used in sort function based on Comparator.

You can't create an array of type `? super T[]` so instead it creates an `Object[]` and uses raw types from there.

> In the for loop why is Type Casting ( to T) needed in sort function based on Comparable and why casting is not necessary in for loop of sort function based on Comparator

In the first case you have `ListIterator<T>` which can only `set(T)` and in the second case you have `ListIterator` which can set any object.

Comment: Isn't it a mistake to allow to set any object in the second case, given that input list is parameterized ?